# How do I extract numbers from the strings in a pandas column of 'object'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named 'x'.

This dataframe is about the size and type of houses (eg 35A, 9B, 50C..) and is of type 'object' and contains missing values.

I want to extract only numbers from this dataframe and convert them to numeric type.

What should I do in this case?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].str[0:2]
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'])
```

***Output***
ValueError: Unable to parse string "9A" at position 3766

Comment: From the comments in the answers, it looks like the data is not necessarily uniform. You may want to study the format of these numbers. If you only need the first digits, then @Tim has the solution for you, but you may have to discard the remaining characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `str.extract` here:

```py
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'].str.extract(r'^(\d+)'))
```

The challenge with trying to use a pure substring approach is that we don't necessarily know how many characters to take.  Regex gets around this problem.

Comment: I tried, but got the following problem: TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: @박혜림 Does _every_ entry in `x` contain a house number beginning with at least one digit?

Comment: Oh, When I checked again, 'x' includes data such as '39D4-1b' as well as data such as 38 and 8, which consist only of numbers.

Comment: The missing value of 'x' is around 50%, would it be better to remove this column?

Answer (score 0):

You are making the assumption that for your strings in the `x` column, the first two characters will always be digits. Unfortunately, you have a row where `x` is `9A` which doesn't convert to a numeric value.